# I am left [slack] jawed by these redundant tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There's a tag called [slack-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slack-api), and another called [slack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slack). There's no info on the wikis suggesting any difference between the two tags.
Should they be merged?

For what it's worth, slack-api has the nicer tag wiki, and it might reduce the likelihood of non-programming questions being posted. The two have roughly equal numbers of questions.

Comment: What if I need help slacking off? Pretty sure this is a common activity for computer programmers.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/303/

Comment: Unfortunately I work with Go, which has fast compile times :-( Terrible language.

Comment: I think it's pretty [slack] nothing has happened yet.